# In what order does Python resolve functions? (why does string.join(lst.append('a')) fail?)

Tags: python, types

How does string.join resolve? I tried using it as below:

```
import string 
list_of_str = ['a','b','c'] 
string.join(list_of_str.append('d'))
```

But got this error instead (exactly the same error in 2.7.2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 318, in join
    return sep.join(words)
TypeError
```

The append does happen, as you can see if you try to join list_of_string again:

```
print string.join(list_of_string)
-->'a b c d'
```

---

here's the code from string.py (couldn't find the code for the builtin str.join() for sep):

```
def join(words, sep = ' '):
    """join(list [,sep]) -> string

    Return a string composed of the words in list, with
    intervening occurrences of sep.  The default separator is a
    single space.

    (joinfields and join are synonymous)

    """
    return sep.join(words)
```

What's going on here? Is this a bug? If it's expected behavior, how does it resolve/why does it happen?  I feel like I'm either about to learn something interesting about the order in which python executes its functions/methods OR I've just hit a historical quirk of Python.

---

Sidenote: of course it works to just do the append beforehand:

```
list_of_string.append('d')
print string.join(list_of_string)
-->'a b c d'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list_of_str.append('d')
```

does not return the new `list_of_str`.

The method `append` has no return value and so returns `None`.

To make it work you can do this:

```
>>> import string
>>> list_of_str = ['a','b','c']
>>> string.join(list_of_str + ['d'])
```

Although that is not very Pythonic and there is no need to `import string`... this way is better:

```
>>> list_of_str = ['a','b','c']
>>> ''.join(list_of_str + ['d'])
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that. Now that you mention it, I remember it from the Python documentation. All functions that don't have a return, return none.  Thanks @jamylak ! (11 minutes until I can accept your answer)

Comment: I also missed the str.join() function while reading through the Python docs. If you don't mind answering: what makes one way more pythonic than the other?

Comment: It's easier and common practice to just create an instance of string such as `''` then import the class an use the methods of the class. As you can see it takes one less line. Other than that, I'm not sure but  I think it's just a python thing :D

Comment: certainly makes sense not to import something new. thanks again!